# Brackets in first column in table give "Missing number, treated as zero" error

Tags: tables, errors, brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error with table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/error-with-table)

I'm writing a table with 4 columns and 1 row. The first column starts with a bracket. It compiles without issues:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
[k]bbb & `def' & [h]bbb & `def' \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If I add another row like that, on the other hand, I receive an error message.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
[k]bbb & `def' & [h]bbb & `def' \\
[k]ccc & `def' & [h]ccc & `def' \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`! Missing number, treated as zero.`

I can avoid the issue by adding some curly braces to the first column, but I'm curious what's going on with LaTeX and brackets in tables here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

LaTeX sees the `[` (from the second row) as the beginning of the optional argument for `\\` and expects a length to follow; since the following token is `k`, an error is triggered. To prevent this, you can use braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
{[k]}bbb & `def' & [h]bbb & `def' \\
{[k]}ccc & `def' & [h]ccc & `def' \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With only one row there's no problem (in fact, the braces around the `[k]` of the first row in my example can be suppressed) since there's no `\\` before the character `[`.

Comment: Why doesn't this problem arise when there is only one row, though?

Comment: @Sverre With one row you dont have \\ before the `[`.

Comment: @Sverre It's the _second_ `[` that causes the issue: the first one cannot be an optional argument as there is no preceding `\\ `.