# Small section in the code causing compiling to take forever

Tags: compiling

This section of my code causes compiling to take a very long time. Can any of you spot any reasons why this occurs?

```
% Table 6
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{25pt}} cccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Event time & CAR & Std. err. & P-value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
[-20,-11] & $0.002$ & $0.004$ & $0.545$ \\ 
[-10,-6] & $0.001$ & $0.002$ & $0.783$ \\ 
[-5,10] & $0.004$ & $0.004$ & $0.309$ \\ 
[11,20] & $0.002$ & $0.004$ & $0.594$ \\ 
[21,60] & $0.003$ & $0.007$ & $0.624$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: The contents of your first column are interpreted as optional arguments of `\\ `. Since they don't contain a valid length, you end up with a document that does not compile properly. To overcome this, you could enclose the contents of each row's first cell in a set of `{}`. (`{[-20,-11]}` instead of `[-20,-11]`.) See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64098/brackets-in-first-column-in-table-give-missing-number-treated-as-zero-error

Comment: note that `\hline \\[-1.8ex] ` is incorrect markup, there should be no `\\ ` after `\hline`

Comment: Perfect this solves my problem. Thank you very much.