# Fatal error, "Can't write on file 'test.pdf'

Tags: errors, compiling, windows

I am not the most experienced latex user, so I hope I can describe the problem accurately. When I compile my tex document I get following message:

! I can't write on file `test.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output

```
! Emergency stop.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox
\fi \fi
l.1 \begin{titlepage}
```

I run Windows 7 if it helps and I use following packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{import}
```

Comment: Do you have the PDF open in Adobe Acrobat or another PDF reader?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you have your PDF file opened in Adobe Reader, perhaps, when you try to compile?

Comment: Note that not all readers lock the .pdf.  Foxit used not to (which was my main reason for using it) but now does.

Comment: @ChrisH Good point. Also, SumatraPDF does not lock, and in fact updates on the fly

Comment: I do not have the pdf file open while I'm compiling. It has been working perfectly the last 3 months. I use SumatraPDF.

Comment: @darthbith as does evince on linux (though it lacks some nice features of other readers).  On windows I use a compile batch file that causes foxit to open a new tab with the latest compile in it - good for comparing output when tweaking - but now it has to muck about with renaming files: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126205/28808

Comment: A few more things to try then: delete the .pdf; delete all other generated files (.aux etc); check the permissions on the folder (is it for example a network location, or some similar case where your permissions could have changed?); copy test.tex to test2.tex and compile that; copy to c:\temp or equivalent and compile there.

Comment: When I delete every generated file and move it all to a new location I get following:

! I can't write on file `Bachelorprojekt.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again>
\edef
l.18 \begin{document}

Comment: What is your OS and how do you compile and where exactly did you store your tex file?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit, compile by F6(pdflatex) and F7(view pdf). I stored my tex file on C:\Users\Anders\Desktop\Bachelor Projekt\test.tex

Comment: But when you use F7 which viewer does it use? Acrobat?

Comment: SumatraPDF, but the error occurs when I compile the document, mening when I press F6 :-)

Comment: Can you create a PDF with a different name? Does the problem persist if you log out and back in? After a reboot?

Comment: I have tried changing the name several times and in different location also. The problem persist when I close all applications or restart the computer. :-)

Comment: !!NOTICE!!
I worked out the problem.

Comment: !!NOTICE!!
I worked out the problem. I haven't got a single clue to why this leads to conflict but.. In my introduction I have a table/tabular 3X3 and in the first cell, first line I wrote "[g]" for indicating gram as a unit. This apparently causes the error, since the error doesn't appear when I just write "g".
Note that I must delete all generated files before compiling again. The error will keep showing if the generated files are not deleted. :-) Thank you guys for your assistance.

Comment: Stupid rule this, that I'm not allowed to answer my own question for the benefit of others. The error can also be fixed by creating a math environment $[g]$.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: For this to be a useful question for future visitors it needs to contain code that produces the problem.  Currently, you just have a list of packages, and this combination compiles fine in a standard document.  Adding the table snippet below from your "Answer" does not produce the described behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

I have been having a similar problem. It is related to the pdf getting locked by Adobe Reader.  Once Adobe opens the file, the compile error occurs.  I delete the files (like the questioner), and compile works, but the error returns when I open it again in Adobe. I don't think the [g], as Martin Schroder suggests, was the solution.

Comment: This problem is for the question [pdftex - How do I open PDF in Adobe Reader DC without locking the file from being updated by pdflatex? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288470/how-do-i-open-pdf-in-adobe-reader-dc-without-locking-the-file-from-being-updated) instead.

Answer (score 3):

!!NOTICE!! I worked out the problem. I haven't got a single clue to why this leads to conflict but.. In my introduction I have a table/tabular and in the first cell, first line I wrote "[g]" for indicating gram as a unit.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Recipes for initial experiments}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
[g]& 5$\%$ cement sub. & 10$\%$ sand sub.\\
\midrule
Water & 225 & 275\\
Sand & 1350 & 1215\\
Cement & 427.5 & 450\\
Ash & 22.5 & 135\\
\bottomrule
\label{opskrift}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This apparently causes the error, since the error doesn't appear when I just write "$[g]$".

```
 \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Recipes for initial experiments}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    $[g]$& 5$\%$ cement sub. & 10$\%$ sand sub.\\
    \midrule
    Water & 225 & 275\\
    Sand & 1350 & 1215\\
    Cement & 427.5 & 450\\
    Ash & 22.5 & 135\\
    \bottomrule
    \label{opskrift}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Note that I must delete all generated files before compiling again. The error will keep showing if the generated files are not deleted. :-) Thank you guys for your assistance.

Comment: You could write `{[g]}` instead, which also works.

Comment: Or perhaps add `\relax` after `\toprule`, same basic issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/error-with-table I suppose.

Comment: That's an error - but how does that cause the "can't write on file test.pdf"?