# Can't have square left bracket [ to begin a row in a table

Tags: tables, brackets

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\label{tab:intro}
\caption{Anonymized data - output example}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule    
      Age & SEX & ETHNIC & STUDIES \\
\midrule
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
   42 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   40 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   45 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
 [48, 51[ &   2 &      1 &     <=3 \\
 [48, 51[ &   1 &      1 &     <=3 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
 [60, 63[ &   2 &      6 &     <=6 \\
   58 &   1 &      1 &       5 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Everything works fine if I remove [, but i need to put them.

This is the error:

`! Paragraph ended before \@argarraycr was complete.`

Comment: Or `\\[0pt]`, which also "eats" the optional argument of `\\`.

Comment: like this:  \\[0pt]48, 51[ &   2 &      1 &     <=3 \\ 
or 
       45 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\{}
      [48, 51[ &   2 &      1 &     <=3 \\

Comment: No duplicate error. I've tried both solution, but are not working, maybe I miss understood them

Comment: Solved!
       45 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\[0pt]
 [48, 51[ &   2 &      1 &     <=3 \\[0pt]
[48, 51[ &   1 &      1 &     <=3 \\
        * &   * &      * &       * \\[0pt]      ............THANKS

Comment: You are wrong: Replacing `\\ ` by `\\\relax` does work, if I make your code snippet complete by `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{booktabs}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. So it is a duplicate.

Comment: using `\relax` is better than using `[0pt]` (it means latex does nothing rather than adding a zero skip)

Comment: an alternative to `\relax` is to enclose the material in the first column in braces, to hide the initial `[`: `...\\{[48, 51[}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's OK in tables but trickier if the cells are in math mode as `{}` affects spacing in math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- good point.  on the other hand, that's one reason why `amsmath` accepts a typed space between `\\ ` and an open bracket to dissociate it from the "vspace" directive.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes

Answer (score 2):

As already explained in the answer to [Error with table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/error-with-table) adding `\relax` to `\\` before rows, that start with `[`, solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\label{tab:intro}
\caption{Anonymized data - output example}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule    
      Age & SEX & ETHNIC & STUDIES \\
\midrule
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
   42 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   40 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   45 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\\relax
 [48, 51[ &   2 &      1 &     <=3 \\\relax
 [48, 51[ &   1 &      1 &     <=3 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\\relax
 [60, 63[ &   2 &      6 &     <=6 \\
   58 &   1 &      1 &       5 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: As shown in the example `<` in text mode will not result in a <. You should either use `\textless`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\label{tab:intro}
\caption{Anonymized data - output example}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule    
      Age & SEX & ETHNIC & STUDIES \\
\midrule
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
   42 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   40 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   45 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\\relax
 [48, 51[ &   2 &      1 &     \textless=3 \\\relax
 [48, 51[ &   1 &      1 &     \textless=3 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\\relax
 [60, 63[ &   2 &      6 &     \textless=6 \\
   58 &   1 &      1 &       5 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

or math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\label{tab:intro}
\caption{Anonymized data - output example}
\[
\begin{array}{llll}
\toprule    
      \text{Age} & \text{SEX} & \text{ETHNIC} & \text{STUDIES} \\
\midrule
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
   42 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   40 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   45 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\\relax
 [48, 51[ &   2 &      1 &     \leq 3 \\\relax
 [48, 51[ &   1 &      1 &     \leq 3 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\\relax
 [60, 63[ &   2 &      6 &     \leq 6 \\
   58 &   1 &      1 &       5 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user124577:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\label{tab:intro}
\caption{Anonymized data - output example}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
  Age & SEX & ETHNIC & STUDIES \\
\midrule
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
   42 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   40 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\
   45 &   1 &      1 &       7 \\[0pt]
 [48, 51[ &   2 &      1 &     <=3 \\[0pt]
[48, 51[ &   1 &      1 &     <=3 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\[0pt]
[60, 63[ &   2 &      6 &     <=6 \\
   58 &   1 &      1 &       5 \\
    * &   * &      * &       * \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```