# Chemmacros reaction(s) environment doesn't display the first reactant if enclosed in square brackets

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros, chemformula

When typing reactions starting with coordinating compounds, I noticed that when the first reactant starts with "[" in both `reaction` and `reactions` environments  the part enclosed in square brackets isn't rendered correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules = all}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
    [ML6]A <=> [ML6]+ + A-
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Neither `pdflatex`, nor `xelatex` show any error messages. Empirically I discovered that adding a pair of square brackets to the reaction(s) environment solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules = all}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}[]
    [ML6]A <=> [ML6]+ + A-
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm also curious why `\begin{reaction}[]` actually works – maybe there are some arguments that reaction(s) environment expects?

Comment: not specific to the reaction environment. it's just how latex works. see e.g. [Error with square bracket in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34466/117534) or just try `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\begin{figure}[Test]\end{figure}\end{document}` and you will get an error about unknown positional arguments.

Comment: @Troy I see. So, what do you think would be the best course of action here: leave a couple of empty `[]` brackets every time, use `{[}` for the first complex, or something else? Also I find it weird that compilers don't complain at all as if `ML6` were a valid argument.

Comment: in this case, I would do `[]` since it seems to be the quickest way to do it. I don't think one has any advantage (apart from flow of typing) over the other. maybe Clemens would have something to say regarding your second statement.

Comment: `chemmacros` doesn't do this anymore with the newest release (should be available in the main distributions in a few days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with an up to date `chemmacros` (v5.8f):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}[2019/09/30]% v5.8f or newer
\chemsetup{modules = reactions}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
  [ML6]A <=> [ML6]+ + A-
\end{reaction}

\begin{reaction}[]
  [ML6]A <=> [ML6]+ + A-
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your competence.