# Strange Error with array environment and brackets

Tags: math-mode, errors

The following produces (in overleaf) an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $$
  s_l = \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    [a]  & \mbox{if } l = j; \\
    [a]  & b.
  \end{array}
  \right.
 $$
\end{document}
```

When I do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $$
  s_l = \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    [a]  & \mbox{if } l = j; \\
    \mbox{[a]}  & b.
  \end{array}
  \right.
 $$
\end{document}
```

it works. That seems strange to me. Is there any
comprehensible reason for this?

Comment: I think this has to do with the trailing double slash thinking that the next square brackets begins its optional parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to solve error with square `[]` brackets on new line in header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512989/5764)

Comment: @PeterGrill is right. Putting `\relax` after the `\\` should resolve the issue, Also, you should probably use `\[`...`\]` instead of `$$`...`$$` (the difference is subtle and only shows up in uncommon circumstances, but it's a good habit to build).

Comment: Thank you. Using `\relax` or `\\{}` resolves the issue.