# square bracket in tikz node annotation makes XeLaTeX compilation failed

Tags: xetex, tikz-node

When I'm using tikz to draw graph with text annotation, I've met a problem that simply adding "[]" around text in annoation would make the compilation using XeLaTeX fail.

For example, this code works as expect:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[draw,align=center] (n) at (0,0) {line1 \\ line2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It generates a box within which shows two lines of text.

But when it becomes as follow, simply add "[ ]", it failed:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[draw,align=center] (n) at (0,0) {line1 \\ [line2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This confused me a lot and I wonder why this would happen.

Comment: latex thinks that you are giving an optional argument to ``\\``, add something between both, e.g. ``\\\relax[line2]`` .

Comment: Thanks for your explaination! I take [this advice that adding an empty group in between](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76346738/21970141) and it works!

Comment: Duplicate of [Error with square bracket in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/error-with-square-bracket-in-table)  <this is not table but same cause anyway.>