# Question concerning an error occurring only one time in two similar examples (tables/array and I cannot find the mistake)

Tags: tables, math-mode, errors, arrays

I'd like to create a table, but I get the strange error "Missing $ inserted \end{frame}". Here is the code. See below for a similar example, where it worked.

Unfortunately, I cannot find my mistake.

Thank you very much for the help.

The non-working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{MyTitle}
\author{Bibabutzemann}
\date{August 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}   
\begin{definition} 
    The blahblah is given by:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}}
            \hline
            \(\begin{array}{|c|ccccc|}
            & a & \cdots & m & \cdots & p\\ \hline
            [W_{1}] & & & & & \\
            \vdots & & & \vdots & & \\
            [W_{i}] & \cdots & \cdots & \psi(x,y) & \cdots & \cdots \\
            \vdots & & & \vdots & & \\
            [W_{k}] & & & \vdots & & \\
            \hline
            \end{array}\)\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{definition}
\end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

The working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{MyTitle}
\author{Bibabutzemann}
\date{August 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}   
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}}
                \hline
                \(\begin{array}{|l|ccc|}
                & u & v & w \\ \hline
                X & 1 & 1 & 1\\
                Y & 1 & 1 & 1\\
                Z & 1 & 1 & 1\\
                \hline
                \end{array}\)\\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
\end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: The error comes from the brackets in the `array`. Remove them and it compiles just fine. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/error-with-square-bracket-in-table

Comment: You can also keep brackets and write `\relax` at the end of lines preceding them.

Comment: @Bibi Thank you very much! It works perfectly fine now.